# Fréchet derivative of $f(x) = x$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Im not sure how to find the Fréchet derivative of the function $f : \mathbb{X} \to \mathbb{X}$ given by $f(x) = x$, where $\mathbb{X}$ is a normed space. I'm not given the dimension of the normed space.

Comment: If $A:\mathbb X\to \mathbb X$ is a continuous operator, can you suggest for each $x\in \mathbb X$ a continuous operator $B_x$ such that $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\lVert A(x+h)-Ax-B_xh\rVert}{\lVert h\rVert}=0\quad ?$$

Answer (score 3):

$f(x+h)-f(x)-{\rm Id}\,h=0$ and so the derivative is the identity.